# Tinymce editor not scrolling to undo or redo location

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-4

I am using tinymce for using a textarea for editing a document  over webbrowser.Undo/Redo feature is working properly but its not scrolling the editor if cursor is up or down in editor.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

At present TinyMCE does not do this.  If you wish to propose this as an updated feature please post your request in the TinyMCE issue tracker:

https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce/issues